# Mixing Audio on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, audio

I have a number of static audio files that I want to be able to dynamically mix together and play on the iPhone (not all at once, most common case is to mix two or three audio streams into one stream).

What shall I use? I know there are OpenAL and Audio Units that could be useful, but which one?
To get a kick-start, is there a concrete code snippet for how to do this somewhere?

Thanks in advance,
/Steve

Answer (score 6):

I recommend you take a look at the some of the Apple documentation and sample code relating to reading files and mixing.

e.g. [Mixing sample code](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/iPhoneMultichannelMixerTest/index.html)

and [Audio Queue Services sample code](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/SpeakHere/index.html)

and [playing audio](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/AQPlayback/PlayingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005343-CH3-SW1)

For a higher level API, use [AudioQueueServices](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioQueueReference/Reference/reference.html) which does a lot of the buffering for you, but if you need to have maximum control and flexbility, then I suggest an AudioUnit along with AudioFileReadPackets which is part of [AudioFileServices](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioFileConvertRef/Reference/reference.html)

Hope that helps,
Ben.