# Record voice and audio file Mixing issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

Here, I am using the following [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667603/mixing-audio-on-the-iphone) attached code for mixing the audio files. But when i am using this for mixing recorded voice and audio file, it's not working for me.So how can i resolve this issue. you Can see my code via this link [Code Link](http://pastebin.com/nU8DK495)

Comment: here you should have put some snippet of code  or logic. i am sure you'll not get good response .so you should edit your question

Comment: @Kamarshad now can you please have a look on this.